# Partitioning a string which has duplicate elements within an iteration

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to iterate over a string and print tuples for each partitioned string, like so:

```
for letter in myString:
...     myList = myString.partition(letter)
...     print(myList)
```

This isn't quite what I want, since `partition` breaks up my string at the **first** instance of the letter,

Let's say myString is "Pizza". I want this `for` loop to give me:

```
('', 'P', 'izza')
('P', 'i', 'zza')
('Pi', 'z', 'za')
('Piz', 'z', 'a')
('Pizz', 'a', '')
```

However, since partition breaks at the **first** "z" it finds, I get something else during the 4th iteration:

```
('', 'P', 'izza')
('P', 'i', 'zza')
('Pi', 'z', 'za')
('Pi', 'z', 'za')
('Pizz', 'a', '')
```

What's the simplest approach to changing my `for` loop?

---

edit:
On another note, why does the `partition` method only take strings as arguments? I'd wanted to solve my problem by passing a number into .partition, by indexing myString.

Comment: partition is a string method that takes part of the string which is another string as an input to know where to make the partition

Answer (score 1):

```
s = "Pizza"
for i in range(len(s)):
    print((s[:i],s[i],s[i+1:]))
```

```
('', 'P', 'izza')
('P', 'i', 'zza')
('Pi', 'z', 'za')
('Piz', 'z', 'a')
('Pizz', 'a', '')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
for i in range(len(myString)):
     myList = (myString[:i], myString[i], myString[i+1:])
     print(myList)
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your use case, you could package this in a generator:

```py
def expose_letters(word):
    for i in range(len(word)):
        yield word[:i], word[i], word[i+1:]


for split in expose_letters("Pizza"):
    print(split)
```